# Vue v-datetime-picker starts in not allowed minimum time

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

When I pass the minimum time (`min` parameter) for the date picker, `02:00` is the minimum for example, but it starts selecting the not allowed value 00:00, if the user clicks OK, it sets the wrong not allowed value.

If I change to an allowed time, 03:00 for example, then I can't click again at 00:00 (expected behavior).

[image: The image shows how the time picker starts once you click it.]

The image shows how the time picker starts once you click it. Note that I passed '02:00' as the minimum time and it started at 00:00 and the user is allowed to click OK and set the wrong time.

PS: I am using the [vuetify-datetime-picker](https://github.com/darrenfang/vuetify-datetime-picker) library

Comment: I believe you should set v-model of the time picker to be equal to the min prop on the initial load of your component or whenever the min value changes.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use min for this, rather use the built in props in `v-time-picker` called `allowed-hours`.

If you want to block 00:00, 01:00 and 02:00, then set allowed-hours like this:

```
<v-time-picker 
    :allowed-hours="v => v > 2 && v <= 23" 
    format="24hr" 
/>
```

More information can be found [here.](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/time-pickers/#allowed-times)

Comment: I tried this solution and it still allows me to click OK when the time is initially set at 00:00. I think this is because I am not using the v-time-picker, it's the [vuetify-datetime-picker](https://github.com/darrenfang/vuetify-datetime-picker). I'll change it in the description.

Comment: Please add a minimum reproducible example as well to see what you're trying to achieve.